# Bulk insert in datastage using teradata connector

Tags: teradata, datastage, bulk-load

I am new to datastage, I created a simple job to get data from .ds file and load it in teradata using teradata connector, in the properties of teradata connector I set the

```
access_method=Bulk, max_session=2, min_session=1,load_type=load, 
max_buffer_size=10000 and max_partition_sessions=1
```

but the job is continously in running state without displaying amount of rows transfered. Whereas when I choose the **access_method=immediate** then it starts to proceed, can any one suggest me the right way to do load in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the nodes you are using? Add APT_CONFIG_FLE environment variable and try to see from director how many nodes are used.  N number of nodes means 2n number of processes. This might help you.

If this doesn't help try looking into the source database connector stage to see if increasing values for any options helps.